# Generate PDF and Attach in Email Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel

I want to generate PDF based on the form.

I have a booking form where clients will fill up, once they click the submit button, laravel 4.2 should have generate a pdf and attach in email and send to me.

Comment: post some code that you have created to solve this problem, no one will write entire feature for you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [domPDF](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/tree/0.4) or [wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy/tree/0.1). Both will allow you to convert html to pdf.

There are Laravel packages for both. I prefer wkhtmltopdf as it uses webkit to render pages, where as domPDF doesn't always render thing as expected, but it is more effort to install.